# can someone explain the definition of $f_x$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} when (x,y)\neq (0,0),$ and $0$ otherwise

$f_x(x,y)= -\frac{2xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{h}=0$

i don't understand specifically $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{h}$ 
When i try plugging in $(h,0)$ into f and then subtract $f(0,0)$... etc, I don't get the same answer. My question is what are they plugging in for $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$

Comment: The limit appearing in your third line, for $\;f_x(0,0)\;$ , seems to be completely wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry i meant $\frac{0}{h}$, i will correct thank you

Comment: Not only that: it should also be $\;h\to\color{red}0\;$ ...!

Comment: yes sorry, I wrote the first one wrong and then copy and pasted it for the rest. I corrected that as well. I understand those mistakes, and that wasn't the part confusing me

Comment: $f_x$ is another notation for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ if you are more familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

$$f_x'(0,0):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h\stackrel{\text{In your case}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0-0}h=0$$

Added for clearity: **the OP** defined

$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\cfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\{}\\0,&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you meant $f(h,0)$, not $f(x,0)$, in your middle equality.

Comment: why did you take the derivative of $f_x$?

Comment: also you wrote what I wrote. :( i don't understand that concept still. is there any way you could break it down further?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Of course. Thanks,

Comment: @artificialHearts You can either use $\;f_x\;$ or  $\;f'_x\;$ to denote *the first* derivative of $\;f\;$ wrt $\;x\;$, and what I wrote after the first equality sign is **the definition** of $\;f_x\;$ at the point $\;(0,0)\;$ ... There's no much more that can be said about that.

Comment: @artificialHearts No. $\;f(0,0)=0\;$ because that's the way **you** defined it ! Read again your question's first line. And $\;f(h,0)=0\;$ because that's what we get upon substituting $\;x=h\;,\;\;y=0\;$ .

Comment: bahahahahahahaha....thank you. now i feel really dumb